# Power BI embedded report shows no records (blank report)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I have a power bi report which is built using power bi report builder. It access postgresql database through on-premises data gateway. It executes a postgresql function as query to get data and show report

This report is embedded on an angular app which is configure similar to the method mentioned in [this C# Corner page](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-embed-powerbi-report-in-angular-6/).

Randomly sometimes, it shows an empty report. On retrying few times like 4-5 times, it shows records. I checked the logs of postgresql. In logs, all the invocations (4-5 times of retrying) are logged. And no error occurred in postgresql function

> "errorLevel": "LOG","sqlerrcode": "00000"

So, all retries invoked the postgresql function. And error occurred in none of them. But still it randomly shows empty report. I am sure it is not due to underlying data in database. Because, in few seconds it shows thousands of records which can not be added in those few seconds while retrying

I created a new report which is a copy of it and used it instead of the old one. This occurs on the new report as well. And the occurrence is super random. Please help me find the cause and resolve it

Comment: To Embed a report, the report should be hosted in Power BI service. Please provide more information about the report and the way you're embedding. Try using Power BI Client REST APIs to Embed the report